# VS 2017 WinForms project quit recognizing user controls in same namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Windows Forms Project that I have been working on for the last several months.

In this solution, I have about 10 custom user controls. A few days ago I was working on the common library that is shared across all of the forms in the application, and then when I went to open the form none of my controls were recognized.

I reverted my changes to the library and the issue persisted. Soon I got to the point where even opening the form crashed VS.

I can compile the solution fine, but I cannot use the visual editor.

None of my custom controls will show up anymore in the toolbox either.  However, I can open them just fine.

[image: Designer Error]

After 2 days of looking online, I have tried the following, to no avail.

- Dynamically reallocated my computer's memory (rebooted)
- Close the solution and reopen it
- Cleaned and rebuilt solution
- Downloaded last release version from source control to a new directory and opened it.
- Removing the controls from the project and readded them
- Deleted the `bin` and `obj` folders
- Deleted the `.vs` folder (stopped VS from crashing as soon as I opened the solution)
- Followed [this MSDN Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ms171843(v=vs.120))
- Refreshed toolbox
- Repaired the Visual Studio Installation
- Uninstalled and Reinstalled Visual Studio
- Copied the solution files from one directory to another
- Reverted my project to an earlier commit from my source control solution
- Removed all NuGet packages
- Removed controls one by one

The only thing that has changed since the last time I was working on this project was that Visual Studio 2017 had recently installed a new update. 
I am at a complete loss, I even resorted to going to page 4 on google.

**UPDATE**
This issue becomes intermittent when I run it on a fresh installation of VS within a Virtual Machine.

Comment: When I deleted the `EMGU.CV.DLL` file from my project it worked after a rebuild, and closing and reopening the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a separate DLL file that I was calling from my project for `EMGU.CV`. Once I removed that reference it worked fine. I created my own DLL wrapper for grabbing a Bitmap Image from the `EMGU.CV` library and the issue have since been resolved.

This makes sense as after I had deleted the NuGet packages, the DLL still remained, but once removed the designer resumed working.